# MVC: Why does this work as an expression but not as a code block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, expression

I'm an ASP/MVC newbie. I'm working in (and modifying) a scaffolded View right now. I have the following simple code, which works fine:

```
<table> 
[... table headers not shown here]
@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <tr>
      <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LandId)
      </td>
      [... other table cells not shown here]
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

As I said, this works fine: In the view (in the column concerned), the values of the property `LandId` of the items in question are displayed.

But now, leaving the other code above the same, I replace the expression

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LandId)
```

with a code block containing (only) that very same expression:

```
@{
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LandId);
}
```

Obviously still expecting to obtain the same output in the view as before. To my surprise,  however, the values of LandId are now no longer displayed in the view (nothing is displayed in this column anymore).

My question: What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using code block everything that is inside that block is just regular C# code. This code is not output to the page automatically. It would be quite confusing if any unused method return value was rendered to the page, wouldn't it?

Looking at your code, method `DisplayFor` returned variable of type `MvcHtmlString`, but is was not used anywhere else in the code so it was discarded.

If you want to output something from the code block, you need to prefix it with `@`. This tells Razor that you understand what you are doing and you want to output the result to the page. In case of your code you can change the code like this:

```
@{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LandId)
}
```

Though this specific concept is not explained very clearly, you can take a look at [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx), it explains how `@` is the magic character in Razor.

Comment: Yes, you're right! And it works now. Thanks! And I'll take a look at the article as well. (I've now also read your edit/addition. ;-) )